# String from XML file and \n

Tags: java, android, xml, libgdx

This is my problem:

I get a `String` from an xml file that includes `"\n"` end of line character. If I put this `String` in a graphics object (in LibGDX Game Window) it has printed with `"\n"` but if I write the `String` directly (so not got from XML file) it will print without `"\n"` and new line occur after the point at `"\n"`.

How can I have this behavior also when I get the `String` from the xml file?

Comment: try replacing the `\n` with `<br/>` in your xml file

Comment: No idea where the issue is, but it sounds like you have ended up with "\n" (two character string) instead of '\n' the single character going into the file.

Comment: It sounds like your `'\n'` character gets escaped when you parse it from the XML file, try to debug the point where you get the `String` from the XML file and check what `String` it returns, it might be that the `String` returned by the XML has the escaped slash: ``\\n``

Comment: @CeilingGecko Yes, you are right. The `String` returned by the XML contains the escaped slash: `\\n`. So i have tried to replace `\\n` with `\n` using replaceAll("\\n", "\n"); but it seems not works...

Comment: I have solved by replacing `\n` with `->`in the XML and, after replace it by replaceAll("->", "\n"); Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved by replacing `\n` with `->` in the XML and then replace it by r`eplaceAll("->", "\n");` Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case you were wondering why your `replaceAll("\\n", "\n");` wasn't working, it was because the first argument in `replaceAll` is a RegEx expression where backslashes have their own meaning. So to represent the Java `String` "\\n" in the RegEx expression you have to escape each backslash with another backslash. Your method call will then become `replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");` And it will do exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks @CeilingGecko you are right. I did not realize that the first argument of `replaceAll()` function is a RegEx.